# convert screen into primefaces data table

Tags: jsf, datatable, primefaces

I need to create a datatable in jsf using primefaces where i need to have one row in which one column contains static data with one button.When i will click on this button then the other columns(within the same row) should display some input text fields with label and data should be populated from database.It means if there are two records coming, then the column in that row should get spanned into the number of rows according to number of records.It means one column will be static and other column in that row should get dynamically spanned and some components should be added in the column within the row.please help me how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi somewhere down the line I found some sample code for dynamically creating rows, further u can nest it as required.

```
     <p:column>
         <f:facet name="header">
             <h:outputLabel value="Field 2" />
         </f:facet>
         <h:outputLabel value="#{myTableVar.Field2}" />
     </p:column>

     <f:facet name="footer">
         <p:commandButton value="New" action="#{myBean.prepareForInsert}" update=":myForm:myPanel"/>
     </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>

<h:panelGrid id="myPanel" columns="2" >
    <h:outputLabel value="Field 1"/>
    <p:inputText id="fld1" value="#{myBean.newRec.field1}" />
    <h:outputLabel value="Field 2"/>
    <p:inputText id="fld2" value="#{myBean.newRec.field2}" />
    <p:commandButton action="#{myBean.createAction}" value="Submit" update="myGrowl myTable" />
</h:panelGrid>
```

When New button is clicked, create an emty instance of newRec in prepareForInsert routine of myBean. So that myPanel is filled with blanks in the fields. On Submit, add the newRec to list_Recs and the new record is diplayed in the data table because of the update on myTable. Hope this helps.